# How to include code from another repository in gitlab registry?

Tags: docker, lua, gitlab-ci, git-submodules

I have a shared registry (a docker image with tools installed for running my code) which is used by multiple repositories. I have created a new repository called LuaServer, which uses code from another repository called LuaDB. In LuaServer I have created a test which requires the code from LuaDB, this test is run in a pipeline on GitLab CI/CD in said shared registry. I get an error during the execution of this test, stating the following:

> spec/serializer_spec.lua:36: module 'luadb.manager.AST' not found:No LuaRocks module found for luadb.manager.AST

Now I tried to directly clone the repository and set it up in the registry (a docker image basically which now has LuaDB), which did not seem to work as the error stays the same. Then I tried to include LuaDB as a submodule for LuaServer, but this still did not solve my problem. Is there a way to work this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try using curl to get files from gitlab repo (check gitlab api)
Gitlab CI/CD pipeline when using it's runner (gitlab shared runners or custom runners) they use a default path that exists on  $CI_PROJECT_DIR env variable. so you can clone you code (luaDB) under $CI_PROJECT_DIR/your_existing_code_luaserver